# Beginner query: Cannot start Gremlin Server on Windows

Tags: windows, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am new to `graph databases` and I am trying to start the `Gremlin Server` using the command: `bin\gremlin-server.bat` 
But, I am getting this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer
>   NOTE: -i is deprecated. Please update your scripts. Using 'install' command...
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.GremlinServerInstall
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.GremlinServerInstall

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: that error appears without your actually putting `-i` in the command? note that you don't need `-i` to start Gremlin Server. you use that flag to install plugins to the server.

Comment: Yes stephen, this is what I am running: 
C:\Users\Yash\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.3.3-bin\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.3.3>bin\gremlin-server.bat

Comment: what happens if you `cd bin` and then do `gremlin-server.bat`? does that change the error? very strange that you are getting error messages related to `-i` when you aren't including that flag.

Comment: @stephenmallette, it was an error with my Java version. I downloaded the 1.8.0 and it started working just fine.